# Cube is not rendering in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to write a basic OpenGL 3.3 program with shaders, buffers, etc. drawing a cube. The problem is that the cube is not drawn. Sorry for such an amout of code, but i feel like the error might be anywhere, because to me it all seems right: display function is looping, shaders are compiled, matrices are passed to shaders. I suspecting that something might be  wrong with culling. Please take a look. Here is the code (I'm using freeglut, first init() is called, then display runs in a loop):

initialization code:

```
struct ProgramData
{
    GLuint theProgram;
    GLuint iModel;
    GLuint iView;
    GLuint iProjection;
};

ProgramData shaderProgram;

ProgramData LoadProgram(const std::string &strVertexShader, 
                        const std::string &strFragmentShader)
{
    std::vector<GLuint> shaderList;

    shaderList.push_back(LoadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, strVertexShader));
    shaderList.push_back(LoadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, strFragmentShader));

    ProgramData data;
    data.theProgram = CreateProgram(shaderList);
    data.iModel = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "mModel");
    data.iView = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "mView");
    data.iProjection = glGetUniformLocation(data.theProgram, "mProjection");

    return data;
}

float cube_vertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

    GREEN_COLOR,
    BLUE_COLOR,
    RED_COLOR,
    BROWN_COLOR,

    GREEN_COLOR,
    BLUE_COLOR,
    RED_COLOR,
    BROWN_COLOR,
};

GLubyte cube_elements[] = {
     0,1,2, 2,3,0,   
     0,3,4, 4,5,0,
     0,5,6, 6,1,0,
     1,6,7, 7,2,1,
     7,4,3, 3,2,7,
     4,7,6, 6,5,4
};

void InitializeProgram()
{

    //initialize vertex buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer_obj);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer_obj);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube_vertices), 
                   cube_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //initialize index buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &index_buffer_obj);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer_obj);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube_elements), 
                           cube_elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    shaderProgram = LoadProgram("shader.vert", "shader.frag");
}

void init()
{
    InitializeProgram();

    int numberOfVertices = 8;
    size_t color_data_offset = sizeof(float) * 3 * numberOfVertices;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer_obj);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 
                          (void*)color_data_offset);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer_obj);
    glBindVertexArray(0);


    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glDepthRange(0.0f, 1.0f);

}
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;

uniform mat4 mProjection;
uniform mat4 mView;
uniform mat4 mModel;

smooth out vec3 theColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mProjection * mView * mModel * vec4(inPosition, 1);
    theColor = color;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330

smooth in vec3 theColor;
out vec4 outputColor;

void main()
{
    outputColor = vec4(theColor, 1);
}
```

draw code:

```
glm::vec3 cam_pos(3, 2, 3);
void display()
{

glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(shaderProgram.theProgram);

glm::mat4 model_matrix = glm::translate(glm::vec3(0, 0, 0));
glm::mat4 view_matrix = glm::lookAt(cam_pos, 
                         glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
glm::mat4 proj_matrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);

glUniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.iProjection, 1, 
                       GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj_matrix));
glUniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.iView, 1, 
                       GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view_matrix));
glUniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.iModel, 1, 
                       GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model_matrix));

glBindVertexArray(vao);
int size;  glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
                                      GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &size);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size / sizeof(GLubyte), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

glBindVertexArray(0);
glUseProgram(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

UPD: in init method when an offset for colors is calculated should be 
`sizeof(float) * 3 * numberOfVertices` instead of 
`sizeof(GLubyte) * 3 * numberOfVertices`, colors are stored as floats. Rendering problem not solved.

SOLVED: thank you for help. See my answer below.

Comment: Are you using a right handed system for your model space?

Comment: I think yes, it's right handed

Comment: Then shouldn't the front face be CCW?

Comment: I'm not really sure, maybe you are right, but I tried with CW, CCW, disabled culling, still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In display() function

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size / sizeof(GLubyte), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

should be changed to

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size / sizeof(GLubyte), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

and in init()

```
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
```

to

```
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
```

So the problem was that I passed to OpenGL incorrect data. Index array is of GLUbyte (1byte size each array element) but I for some reason decided it was GLushort (2bytes).

edit: doesn't matter a lot, but up vector (when generating camera matrix) should be not `glm::vec3(0, 0, 1)` but `glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)`

Comment: Probably because `GLubyte` is not a hardware supported index size and somewhere deep down you already knew this ;) Stick to 16-bit / 32-bit indices for desktop GPUs and most embedded GPUs as well. Using 8-bit indices requires the driver to do extra work since the hardware cannot use them. Smaller sized indices are always better, but 8-bit indices are never good - use the smallest size you can get away with as long as it is hardware supported.

Answer (score 3):

On thing I did spot when glancing over your code is the following line from your vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = mProjection * mView * mModel * vec4(inPosition, 0);
```

That `0` should really be a `1.0`.

Comment: +1 only vectors would have 0 for w, points should have 1 for translation to work.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, fixed that, but the problem still exists